# Множественное программное создание однотипных TextView в цикле

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть необходимость добавления на экран большого количества TextView в цикле, id TextView должны быть взяты из БД, я их уже вытащил, а вот  задать TextView с различными id не получается.

P.S. выделенная часть должна в цикле заполняться именами из БД

TextView ***txtView***=new TextView(getApplicationContext());

```
LinearLayout linearLayout= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout5);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
TextView txtView=new TextView(getApplicationContext());
txtView.setText(telephone+" "+kluch);
linearLayout.addView(txtView);
```

Comment: А чем вам RecyclerView или List не подходит? Получаете из базы номера и в модели id будет, манипуляции проще проводить.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте метод [setId(int)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setId(int)). Чтобы идентификаторы не пересекались с сгенерированными при компиляции в классе R.id можно использовать [generateViewId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()). Либо используйте теги (метод [setTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object))).

Однако ваше решение с генерацией множества View выглядит сомнительным. Возможно вам стоит использовать RecyclerView.